# Matrix multiplication inside for loop in Scilab

Tags: scilab

I want to multiply each column of matrix A by matrix C. For this I am using for loop as follows:

```
A=[ 0.   1.   2.   3;0.   1.   2.   3.]
C=[2 0;0 2]. 
for i=1:4
B(i)=C*A(:,i);
end
```

But no matrix `B(i)` is displaying.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `C*A(:,i)` is a column matrix. To store all columns in a single matrix, you have to use the same notation you used to retrieve a single column from `A`. Therefore, you should write this in your loop:

```
B(:,i) = C * A(:,i);
```